# Change background on scroll

Tags: jquery, background-color

How can i make the background-color change when scrolling, not based on the distance from top specifically, but based on the div background? I don't know if you understand, but here is an example of what i want like this site here: http://readymag.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).scroll(function()
{
    $('body').css('background-color','#9966'+($(this).scrollTop()/10))
});
```

**OR**

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    $('body').css('background-color','#9966'+($(this).scrollTop()/10));
});
```

Comment: http://www.developerdrive.com/2011/10/how-to-change-a-pages-background-as-the-user-scrolls/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a plugin like [Waypoint](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) which allows you to trigger a function depending where you are scrolling.

In your case, you could trigger a function that would change the background color.